# Where can I find reusable ASP.NET MVC UI components?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and am still adjusting to the drastic switch from WebForms.  I was a bit happy when I found that the idea of ready-made components is not totally gone when I found http://nuget.org/packages/TinyMCE.JQuery, a nuget package that installs an HTML editor component such that it just takes the addition of a UIHint attribute to use it.

My question is where do I go to find more things like this which will help me get closer to the level of efficiency I got used to with WebForms/AjaxToolkit (not withstanding my obvious need to keep learning MVC best practices)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about MVC is you don't need server controls, you now have the freedom to use anything HTML/CSS/JS

If you want something cohesive try:
http://www.kendoui.com/web.aspx

Comment: thanks - wow the autocomplete demo that hooks up to the netflix odata source is cool!

Comment: I'm also working on an article about writing your own Helpers (aka controls) for MVC using Fluent API's. You can get the source code on GitHub now https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/FluentHtmlHelpers

Answer (score 0):

There's tons of stuff in NuGet, just go searching at NuGet.org